# NullPointerException- When I try to switch activities using a button

Tags: android, android-button

I am really trying to figure this out, but I can't find the answer.
I checked the XML file and it looks fine to me. tried several versions of this code and received the same result every time:

```
'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener 
(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference at com.example.owner.androidlab01.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:25)
```

Activity class:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

    protected static final String ACTIVITY_NAME = "StartActivity";

    private Button imaButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_items);
        Log.i(ACTIVITY_NAME, "In onCreate()");

        imaButton = findViewById(R.id.imbutton);
        imaButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this , ListItemsActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent ,50);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".StartActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_message"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imbutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ButtonText" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the name of your xml layout file where your button is located?

Comment: Just to confirm, `activity_list_items.xml` is the name of the XML you have in your question?

Comment: You need to cast the findViewById. Like this
imaButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imButton);

Comment: @UmangBurman - Activity_Start

Comment: @Deepakkaku- I tried that. It didn't solve it

Comment: Try extending the class as `AppCompatActivity` instead of just `Acticity`

Comment: @UmangBurman It doesn't let me add it.

Comment: Oh can you show your Gradle please

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried casting this object?

```
imaButton = findViewById(R.id.imbutton);
```

I think casting that to `Button` should do it:

```
imaButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imbutton);
```